# How to upload a picture via an API?

Tags: json, vba, api

I'm trying to upload a file to imgBB using an API.

I get the error message:

> {"status_code":400,"error":{"message":"Empty upload source.","code":130},"status_txt":"Bad Request"}

```vb
Sub EncodeFile()
Dim strPicPath As String
Dim TestFile As String
strPicPath = "X:\xxxxxxx\xxxxx.png"
Const adTypeBinary = 1          ' Binary file is encoded

' Variables for encoding
Dim objXML
Dim objDocElem

' Variable for reading binary picture
Dim objStream

' Open data stream from picture
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile (strPicPath)

' Create XML Document object and root node
' that will contain the data
Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXml2.DOMDocument")
Set objDocElem = objXML.createElement("Base64Data")
objDocElem.DataType = "bin.base64"

' Set binary value
objDocElem.nodeTypedValue = objStream.Read()

' Get base64 value
TestFile = objDocElem.Text

With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    .Open "POST", "https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
    .send TestFile
    MsgBox (.ResponseText)
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure if your body is being sent properly. You're sending the `XMLDocument.Text` instead of `XMLDocument.XML` and you're requesting communication in JSON in the headers. It may be failing to read your request because of that.

Comment: Also, the [API help page](https://api.imgbb.com/) for ImgBB says the image data needs to be labelled "image", not "Base64Data". It might be looking for the tag "image" and not finding anything.

Answer (score 1):

As @Toddleson notes, the content of the POST should be the base64 of the file, assigned to a parameter "image".  You can see that in the CURL example on the API page:

`"image=R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"`

I would factor out the Base64 functionality into a re-usable function:

```vb
Sub EncodeFile()
    Dim strPicPath As String
    
    strPicPath = "X:\xxxxxxx\xxxxx.png"
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", "https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        '.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json" 'not sending json...
        .send "image=" & FileToBase64(strPicPath)
        MsgBox .ResponseText
    End With
End Sub

'return the contents of a file as Base64
Function FileToBase64(fPath As String) As String
    Const adTypeBinary = 1          ' Binary file is encoded
    Dim objStream As Object, objXML As Object, objDocElem As Object
    
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    objStream.Open
    objStream.LoadFromFile fPath
    
    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXml2.DOMDocument")
    Set objDocElem = objXML.createElement("Base64Data")
    objDocElem.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objDocElem.nodeTypedValue = objStream.Read()
    objStream.Close
    FileToBase64 = objDocElem.Text
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It didn't work though. Got the same error message as before. Any clue what might be the problem? No clue how to debug. I double checked the key and the path to the picture.

Comment: Sorry I don't have anything else to suggest.